# Daemonset pod to check a specific service that is different for every pod

Tags: clickhouse

I have a clickhouse cluster that is running on pods in kubernetes and I have a clickhouse-explorer that should be checking one clickhouse node each. I was thinking about using daemonset for this but I don't know how to force in the config that each pod to connect to a different service. Note I don't want to use sidecontainer for the clickhouse.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Why you don't use https://github.com/Altinity/clickhouse-operator ?

Comment: I am actually using that.